# Retrofit/GSON null field leads to null object

Tags: json, retrofit2

I have a json structure with fields which can become null. Like this:

```
{ "objectA":{"fieldA":null}, "objectB":{"fieldB1":123,"fieldB2":"abcdef"} }
```

The problem is that in this case the whole object representing the structure becomes null too. While if the filed is not null like

```
... {"fieldA":"xyz"} ...
```

the deserialization works fine. How can this happen? I have tested my json with Gson alone and it works right (only fieldA is null) so the problem must be in retrofit?!

My retrofit/gson dependencies are:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

The response structure looks like this:

```
public class ObjectResponse extends BaseResponse {

 @SerializedName("objectA")
 private ObjectA objectA;

 public ObjectA getObjectA() {
    return objectA;
 }
}

public class ObjectA {

 @SerializedName("fieldA")
 private String fieldA;

 public String getFieldA() {
    return fieldA;
 }
}

public class BaseResponse {

 @SerializedName("objectB")
 private ObjectB objectB;

 public ObjectB get ObjectB() {
    return objectB;
 }
}

public class ObjectB {

 @SerializedName("fieldB1")
 private int fieldB1;
 @SerializedName("fieldB2")
 private String fieldB2;

 public int getFieldB1() {
   return fieldB1;
 }

 public String getFieldB2() {
   return fieldB2;
 }
}
```

Comment: That's strange... Could you please post the definition of your models and which version of retrofit you're using pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the reason is not the null field, however it is a hint. The reason (in my case) the fields were null was that there was a logical reject on the server side which leads to a HTTP response code set also to a error value. Retrofit however does not perform the conversion from json to java object if response code is outside of [200..300).